# Rails scope on belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Imagine a Book and a Chapter model. Each Chapter `belongs_to :book`, and a Book `has_many :chapters`. We have scopes on the Chapter, for example `:very_long` returns chapters with over 300 pages.

Many times we want to get all books with any chapters over 300 pages. The way we usually achieve this is like so:

```
# book.rb
scope :has_very_long_chapter, -> { where(id: Chapter.very_long.select(:book_id) }
```

However, as you can imagine, it gets pretty tedious to proxy the scope every time we want to filter Books by chapter scopes. Is there any more idiomatic or cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To get those books you can use [`ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge%21), and you don't have to use another scope:

```
Book.joins(:chapters).merge(Chapter.very_long)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one thing you could do would be to use `joins/merge`

```
class Book < ARBase
  scope :with_long_chapters, ->{ joins(:chapter).merge(Chapter.very_long) }
end

class Chapter < ARBase
  scope :very_long, -> { logic for querying chapters with over 300 pages }
end
```

EDIT(#2): A more reusable scope

```
class Book < ARBase
  scope :by_chapter_page_count, ->(pages){ joins(:chapter).merge(Chapter.by_page_count pages) }
  scope :with_climax, -> { joins(:chapter).merge(Chapter.by_category :climax) }

  scope :long_with_climax, -> { by_chapter_page_count(400).with_climax }
end

class Chapter < ARBase
  scope :by_page_count, ->(pages) { where("pages > ?", pages }
  scope :by_category, ->(category) { where category: category }
end

Book.by_chapter_page_count(100)
```

You can get fairly creative with how you write your scopes

Comment: that is a bit cleaner but it doesn't solve the issue of having to write a new scope every time I want to reuse one on the child model.

Comment: @jtmarmon could you clarify what you mean by writing a new scope every time you want to reuse the one on the child model? I'm not quite sure I understand what you are getting at.  If you want to have a different query, you are going to have to define new scopes.

Comment: @jtmarmon Let me revise my answer a little, to see if we can make the scope more reusable.

Comment: the problem is not the reusability of the scopes themselves (as improved in your edit). the problem is that you have to create a proxy scope on the Book model every time you want to get books by the Chapter model. for example, if i was to add a :climax scope on Chapter, returning all chapters that are labeled as climaxes, then to get all books that have a climax (bad example but you get the idea) i'd have to define another proxy scope on the Book, like `scope :with_climax`

Comment: @jtmarmon well ya... kinda... if you want to have scopes your going to have to define them, and if you want join scopes of two separate models, and get and inner join, then this is the cleanest way to do that.

Comment: However, depending on your business logic and how you have setup you tables, you can get very creative with scopes. Ill try to post another example.